# How can i combine values in two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

i have this 4 Arrays:

```js
const units = [[ "deg" ], [ "px" , "px" ]];
const values = [[ 0 ], [ 0 , 0 , 0 ]];
```

I wanto to combine to this:

```js
const result = ["0deg", "0px, 0px, 0"];
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share your code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods, one for iterating over the values in your `values` array, and another for iterating over the values in each inner array. The outer map is used to map the array values inside of `values` to strings. These string are formed by mapping the inner arrays to individual `"<number><unit>"` strings. The `<number>` (ie: `n`) is retrieved by the inner callback method from `.map()`. The `<unit>` is calculated by retrieving the associated array value from the `units` array using the indexes `i` and `j`. If the associated value returns a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value (eg: undefined), then it will default to an empty string. This array of `["<number><unit>", ...]` strings can then be joined together to form one string, separated by a comma using [`.join(', ')`](https://www.google.com/search?q=join%20mdn&oq=join%20mdn&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.1457j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

```js
const units = [[ "deg" ], [ "px" , "px" ]];
const values = [[ 0 ], [ 0 , 0 , 0 ]];

const result = values.map(
  (arr, i) => arr.map((n, j) => `${n}${units[i][j] || ""}`).join(', ')
);
console.log(result);
```